# Transferring whole Linux system to a new disk

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, lvm

Few weeks back I installed Linux as a virtual machine on my Windows 7 system, but I didn't give much thought to (or miscalculated) the size of various partitions and even worse I'm not using `lvm`. Today I tried to installed Qt 5.0 SDK which required around 500 MB of space in `/tmp` which I didn't have, but other partitions had quite a bit of space. The partition scheme is:

> primary partitions:
>
> /boot 60M ext4
>
> extended partitions:
>
> /     6.5G  ext4
>
> swap  512M  ext4
>
> /tmp  512M  ext4
>
> /var  1G    ext4
>
> /home 5G    ext4

I booted from an Ubuntu live cd and used `gparted` to get resize the `/tmp` partition, problem solved! But here I can see the benefit of using 'lvm'.

I want to create a new system which uses `lvm`. But instead of making a fresh install I think we can transfer my current system to a new hard disk.

I added another 100 GB virtual hard disk to this virtual machine, created a 256 MB /boot primary partition and the rest of the space for a `lvm` partition. Now I have the various partitions (except /boot) on logical volumes (following [UbuntuDesktopLVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM)). Now comes the hard part, how do I move the system to this new disk properly?

Current configuration: Linux Mint 13 32 bit on Windows 7 32 bit using VirtualBox 4.2.

Answer (score 3):

- use tar (as root) to pack the whole system into a .tar.gz file.
- set up partitions for the new system, mount all disks where they belong
- untar everything to the new system
- check files like /etc/fstab to make sure everything is still valid.

tar is able to store permission, times and owners of all files. Therefore the new system should look exactly like the old one.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/clonezilla.html) that will walk you through most of how to clone you existing VMs partition to the new one you created on the 2nd virtual device.

Comment: clonezilla looks promising let me try it out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using 'VboxManage' to expand your virtual drive. There is no need to do new installation with new enlarged virtual drive and transferring old system on it. I've already done this.

The steps ave very simple ([example procedure](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/)):

1. Stop the virtual machine.
2. Expanding drive over 'VboxManage'.
3. Loading existing virtual machine from some LiveCD like 'SystemRescueCD'.
4. Mounting your virtual HDD and running [resize2fs.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ext4grow)